# TypeError: postHandleFormChange is not a function Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get *TypeError: postHandleFormChange is not a function Error".* Whats wrong?

in App.js

```
function App() {
    const [post, setPost] = useState('')

const postHandleFormChange = (post) => {
        setPost(post)
    }
return (
        <div className="container">

            <Switch>                
                <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}
                         post={post} handleFormPost={handleFormPost}
                                postHandleFormChange={postHandleFormChange}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
```

in Profile.js

```
const Profile = ({
                     post, postHandleFormChange
                 },) => {
const postHandleChange = (event) => {
        postHandleFormChange(event.target.value)
    }
return (
        <div className="container-profile">
            <h3>Welcome</h3>
            <form>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="post" value={post} onChange={postHandleChange}/>
                    <button type="submit">Post</button>
                </label>
            </form>                        
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the props to the `<Route>` component while you should be passing them to the `<Profile>` component. Rewrite your code in `App.js` like that:

```
<Switch>                
    <Route path="/profile">
       <Profile post={post} handleFormPost={handleFormPost}
                 postHandleFormChange={postHandleFormChange} />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<Route />` use the `render` prop when you have to pass props to the component.

```
<Route path="/profile" render={(routeProps) => 
  <Profile 
    post={post}
    handleFormPost={handleFormPost}
    postHandleFormChange={postHandleFormChange}
    {...routeProps}
  />
} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your props in `Route` which is wrong but also I see another thing that is missing, you do not have props `handleFormPost` in `Profile` component. You should add it also in return part depends on how you want to use it

```
const Profile = ({
                     post, postHandleFormChange, handleFormPost
                 },) => {
const postHandleChange = (event) => {
        postHandleFormChange(event.target.value)
    }
return (
        <div className="container-profile">
            <h3>Welcome</h3>
            <form>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="post" value={post} onChange={postHandleChange}/>
                    <button type="submit">Post</button>
                </label>
            </form>                        
        </div>
    )
}
```

App part

```
function App() {
    const [post, setPost] = useState('')

const postHandleFormChange = (post) => {
        setPost(post)
    }
return (
        <div className="container">

            <Switch>                
                <Profile post={post} handleFormPost={handleFormPost}
                postHandleFormChange={postHandleFormChange} />
           </Switch>
        </div>
    )
```